# How can we write a non-central chi-squared distribution as gamma distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, random, gamma-distribution, chi-squared

Consider a random variable that has a non-central chi-squared distribution
\begin{eqnarray*}
L & = & \chi_{1}^{2}(b^{2}),
\end{eqnarray*}
where$\chi_{1}^{2}(b^{2})$ represents a non-central chi-squared with
one degree of freedom. In fact $\chi_{1}^{2}(b^{2})$ is the square
of $\mathcal{N}(b,1)$. How can we write $L$ as a Gamma distribution
please? I know that if $b=0,$ we can write 
\begin{eqnarray*}
L & \sim & \Gamma(\frac{1}{2},2).
\end{eqnarray*}
What happens when $b\neq0$ please? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the noncentrality parameter is nonzero, the distribution of $L$ is a mixture of infinitely-many central Chi-square distributions (which are Gamma distributions with appropriate parameters). Specifically, the density function of $L$ is 
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-b^2/2} (b^2/2)^n}{n!} g_n(x)
$$
where $g_n(x)$ is the density function for a [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Characterization_using_shape_k_and_scale_%CE%B8) with parameters $k=n+{1\over 2},\theta=2:$
$$g_n(x)=\frac{x^{(n+{1\over 2})-1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{2^{n+{1\over 2}}\Gamma(n+{1\over 2})}[x > 0].
$$

A sketch of the derivation of this density is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution#Derivation_of_the_pdf) (in sections 3, 3.1).

Note: The derivation uses the Taylor series  $$\cosh x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$ and the fact that $${\Gamma(n+{1\over 2})\over\Gamma(2n+1)}={\sqrt{\pi}\over 4^n\,n!}.$$